# Pass a parameter to a parameterized query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a query from a database table that contains a parameter. Then use that query to update another table but I need to be able to pass another parameter to that update statement.

```
declare @locnum int
set @locnum = 032

declare @tempPersonID int
set @tempPersonID = 10008

declare @passwordQuery varchar(max)
set @passwordQuery = (select passwordQuery from location where locationNum = @locnum)

select @passwordQuery

update tempPerson 
set [password] = @passwordQuery
where tempPersonID = @tempPersonID

select *
from tempPerson
```

`select @passwordQuery` returns `(select left(firstname,1) + left(lastname,1)  + custom as [password] from tempPerson where tempPersonID = @tempPersonID)`. I need to able to use the `@tempPersomID` parameter in this query and the where statement.

Comment: The only way to do that us using `dynamic sql` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. Also you know you can assign a variable directly in a `select` e.g. `select @passwordQuery = passwordQuery from location where locationNum = @locnum`

Comment: @DaleBurrell I've been looking over the link there and I don't understand how to get the tempPersonID passed down to the `@passwordQuery` variable. I've not worked with `dynamic sql` before. Can you provide the application for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as you are updating the record that you are selecting the information from you only need the following as your `@passwordQuery`:

```
left(firstname,1) + left(lastname,1)  + [custom]
```

Then the following code takes your code and adapts it for dynamic SQL:

```
declare @locnum int = 032, @tempPersonID int = 10008, @passwordQuery varchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max), @params nvarchar(max);

select @passwordQuery = passwordQuery from [location] where locationNum = @locnum;

-- select @passwordQuery

set @sql = 'update tempPerson set [password] = ' + @passwordQuery
  + ' where tempPersonID = @tempPersonID';
set @params = '@tempPersonID int';

execute sp_executesql @sql, @params, @tempPersonID = @tempPersonID; 

select *
from tempPerson
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Execute Dynamic SQL Statements with parameter using either the `EXEC` or `sp_ExecuteSQL` Statements.

In your Case, The `sp_ExecuteSQL`seems more suitable. The Syntax for the same is as below

```
sp_executesql [ @stmt = ] statement  
[   
  { , [ @params = ] N'@parameter_name data_type [ OUT | OUTPUT ][ ,...n ]' }   
     { , [ @param1 = ] 'value1' [ ,...n ] }  
]
```

So Your Entire Script can be re-written as below :

```
DECLARE @locnum INT
        @tempPersonID INT,
        @passwordQuery VARCHAR(MAX),
        @params VARCHAR(500),
        @ParamOut VARCHAR(500)

SELECT  
    @locnum = 032,
    @tempPersonID = 10008,
    @params = N'@tempPersonID INT,@MyPwd VARCHAR(500) OUTPUT'

SELECT
    @passwordQuery = 'SET @MyPwd = ('+passwordQuery+')'
    FROM Location 
        WHERE LocationNum = @locnum


sp_ExecuteSQL(@passwordQuery,@params,@tempPersonID,@MyPwd = @ParamOut OUTPUT )

UPDATE tempPerson 
    SET 
        [password] = @ParamOut
    WHERE tempPersonID = @tempPersonID

select *
from tempPerson
```